# make an api call in foreach loop and push the result in another array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an api call in a for each loop. When I make an api call, the function returns the Promise. I want use that return response and check if the promise is resolved (then do something) and if rejected (then do something). But, everytime in the foreach loop, first the api makes both the calls and then goes to the then() part. 
What I want is in foreach loop, make an api call -> check if resolved or rejected -> do something -> make an api call -> check if resolved or rejected -> do something and so on.

//cannot change the below implementation. I need to use this already created function

```
    const callApiFunction = options => {
      const callback = (resolve, reject) => {
      something.call(options, resolve, reject)
    };
      return new Promise(callback);         
     }
```

//First attempt

```
const a =[];
const b =[];
list.forEach(listelement => {
    callApiFunction(options)
     .then(() => {
         a.push(listelement);
       })
     .catch(() => {
        b.push(listelement);
     });
});
```

//Second attempt

```
    const a =[];
    const b =[];
   list.forEach(listelement => {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      callApiFunction(options);
      resolve(listelement);
      reject(listelement);
    });
    promise.then((listelement) => {
      a.push(listelement);
    })
    .catch((listelement) => {
      b.push(listelement);
    });
  });
```

What happens in my second code block is, callApiFunction is first executed twice if list.length = 2 and then, `then` is executed twice.
I want the callApiFunction is executed and list[0] -> then or catch executes accordingly
callApiFunction is executed and list[1] -> then or catch executes accordingly

Comment: `forEach()` is not `async` aware. You need to use `reduce()` to pass the promise chain through, or use a normal `for` loop with one or more `await` statements in the block.

Comment: Also, calling `resolve(listelement)` on one line and then `reject(listelement)` on the next line of code makes absolutely no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this variant with `for-of` loop and `await` work for you?

```js
'use strict';

async function separate(list) {
  const a = [];
  const b = [];

  for (const listelement of list) {
    try {
      await callApiFunction(options);
      a.push(listelement);
    } catch (err) {
      b.push(listelement);
    }
  }

  return [a, b];
}

separate([1, 2, 3]).then(([good, bad]) => {
  console.log(`Success:\n${good.join('\n')}\n\nErrors:\n${bad.join('\n')}\n`);
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can export `async` function and then `await` it in the importing module.

Comment: @RohitShetty I've updated the example to illustrate the function usage.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. It is a great starting point and I am able to resolve my error. Thanks!